# Xcode 4 code loses syntax coloring when importing project from Xcode 3

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, xcode4

I have just upgraded to the new Xcode 4 and the code is not colored has it should be.
I am trying to use a project that I created on Xcode 3.

For instance, the string 'NSString' is not colored in my custom code, but when I switch to Apple's code (NSString.h for ex.) everything is well colored.

How can I fix that?

Thanks a lot,
Martin

Comment: Are you getting any errors when building?

Comment: eplogee has a good point: it's possible Xcode is not recognizing symbols, which can be a symptom of a screwed up project.

Comment: I'm getting some warnings. Warnings can cause my problem?

Comment: MartinMoizard: No, errors. The syntax highlighter should work as long as the code compiles (specifically, as long as it is syntactically valid). You should fix those warnings, but for other reasons.

Comment: Is your prefix.pch file properly formatted ? I had tabs inside mine and it prevented the syntax coloring and autocompletion from working properly.

Comment: I also have tab in mine... I already switched back to Xcode 3. Only removing tabs characters from this file fixed the problem?

Comment: Well, it did for me, but now the syntax coloring went away again, along with the Symbol Navigator contents. Are you sure you are using the proper compiler, in your Project settings ? It should be LLVM GCC4.2

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Open the Organizer (`Window > Organizer`) and select the **Projects** mode. Select your project in the left-hand view and then click the `Delete…` button for the project's **Derived Data**.

This will delete the code sense index for the project and force Xcode to rebuild the index, which should fix the problem.

Comment: It's working but when I restart Xcode everything is broken again

Comment: cmd + ctrl + shift + K

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by prefixing all my project search paths with "$(SOURCE_ROOT)/" instead of just using a project relative path. Eg "Include" becomes "$(SOURCE_ROOT)/Include".

Do this and then force a rebuild of the index by deleting the projects derived data from the organizer.

Comment: I tried to do this, but now Xcode shows no Derived Data directory in the Organiser and the "code sense" doesn't even detect classes it used to!  Xcode 4 is acting very broken, but only on iOS projects, not Mac OS X projects...

Comment: Nevermind!  I missed the bit that I needed to have quotes around it -- the directory containing my code has spaces in the path -- and now it works flawlessly!  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

After trying most, if not all, of the steps above, I have succeeded in restoring my colorful Xcode eye candy by finding and deleting (in Finder) all of the derived data created from my project (there were several folders for my project that were lingering even after deletion from the Window > Organizer menu).

My project's folders that needed deletion were located in ~Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Answer (score 1):

Also try this, select all(command + A) from your Prefix.pch file -> cut it(command + X) -> Build(command + B)(don't worry for error) -> paste(whatever you copy from Prefic.pch file in that file only)(commmand + V) -> Build again (command + B).

Answer (score 0):

Try Product -> Clean and then Product -> Build

Answer (score 0):

Remove the files from your project (just remove, don't delete them!) and re-import them.

Comment: Ugh, better solutions than this—especially on a big project.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the permissions on the folder where Xcode stores the code-sense cache is broken. If the cache cannot be correctly written or read when you launch Xcode, it will behave as you describe.

Try locating the folder (you can locate it in the organizer. Hit the arrow next to the path.) and reset its permissions in the Get Info dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is another cause for this issue, it had been happening to me with beta versions of Xcode, you need to check that the .m file is added to the target in order to make it add color to the classes and enable the autocompletion.

You can check it out in the Xcode inspector [image]

Hope this helps,

best regards,

Jorge.